# Are invertible sheaves on projective line $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ all twisting sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(n)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-space

Suppose $k$ is a field. Invertible sheaves on $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ are of the form $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(D)$ for some divisor $D$. For simplicity we may assume $D=x$ for some closed point $x\in |\mathbb{P}_k^1|$. The question is to show:

> $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(D)\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(\mathrm{deg}\,x)$$

as sheaves on $\mathbb{P}_k^1$, here $\mathrm{deg}\,x=[k(x):k]$, $k(x)$ being the residue field of $x$.

Comment: Show that $D$ is linearly equivalent to $\deg x$ times the point at infinity by looking at the polynomial generating the extension $k(x)/k$.

Comment: Say $k = \Bbb{Q}$ your projective space is $\{ [u:v], (u,v) \in \overline{k}^2, uv \ne 0\}$ its function field is $k(u/v)$ and $(u/v)^2+1$ has two zeros at $[i:1], [-i:1]$ and a double pole at $[1:0]$. What is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}([i:1] + [-i:1]),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(2[1:0])$ ?